# Why is Eclipse not generating 'R' in the gen folder?

Tags: android

Okay so here is what I am doing, I am trying to create a very simple android application and since it is my first time I tried following a tutorial from hackaday.com

http://hackaday.com/2010/07/21/android-development-101-part-3introduction-to-databases/

And now I have all the codes in place. The only problem is, I am getting an error in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. Here is my code

```
package com.ernest.randomquotes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.ernest.randomquotes.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    **@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}**
```

As you can see I even imported the `com.ernest.randomquotes.R` but still it returns an error. I also tried deleting the gen folder since I read a few answers here in stackoverflow and it worked for them. I get that the `.R` is generated in the gen folder right? So why is it not generating for me?

Believe me I've researched for hours and I still encounter errors

Comment: Just check other resource files also if they have a errors or problem then also R.java file is not generated. In eclipse `View -> Problem`

Comment: There are no other errors.

Comment: Should there be an `R.java` in the gen folder?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe Please see my answer, it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Create New Project Clean or Build Your Project and Remove this `import com.ernest.randomquotes.R;` line, Because After Creation of project the `R file` is not generated automatically.

Comment: After I have added the new codes. It returns to the last error in ALL codes that refers to `R.` any ideas why this happens and how to conteract it?

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the project, reopen then build/clean. if that doesn't work, restart eclipse. Hope that will do. Also, check in your activity files if andriod.R is imported? that causes the problem sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't import com.ernest.randomquotes.R .clean your project and try again then restart...try for two three times clean and build , you will get

Answer (score 1):

R.java in gen folder is not generated when is something wrong in your res folder, if is not showing(sometimes, it happens) clean the project and the error should light up